# Decode this MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB group query. I udnerstand most of it, but the 'if' condition bit in the 'reduce' function is confusing me. I am not sure what the purpose of that is.

```
db.users.group({
    "initial": {
        "countstar": 0
    },
    "reduce": function(obj, prev) {
        if (true != null) if (true instanceof Array) prev.countstar += true.length;
        else prev.countstar++;
    },
    "cond": {
        "location": null
    }
});
```

I know what the 'initial' parameter does. I also know what the 'cond' parameter is doing. However, the whole bit inside the 'reduce' parameter is confusing.

Also, what is the equivalent SQL?

Comment: i am guessing that somewhere there is a variable called true and the code checks on how to handle it?

Comment: @alernerdev Okay, and what do the two consecutive if conditions mean? Are they nested?

Comment: yes, nested.  the gist of it is:  check if its not null. if its not, check if its array.  if it is an array, add the length of the array.  if its not an array, just increment by one.  you can make it more readable by breaking it up into multiple lines with indents, and putting in curly braces for good measure.  You can also take this code, setup different values of "true" and observe what happens

Comment: Thanks! Another question: What is the equivalent SQL for the MongoDB query?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to understand if we reformat it:

```
db.users.group({
   "initial": { "countstar": 0 },
   "reduce": function(obj, prev) {
        if (true != null) {
            if (true instanceof Array)
                prev.countstar += true.length;
            else 
                prev.countstar++;
        }
    },
    "cond": { "location": null }
 });
```

Something's definitely wrong with this, because `true` is a boolean value in Javascript, so the first condition always holds, the second condition never holds, and `true.length` is `undefined`. It looks like `true` should instead by some property of `obj`. In that case, what the code does, sort of, is sum the lengths of the whatever array property `true` is supposed to refer to, counting non-array values as length 1 arrays. Where did this code come from? Does it actually work and give you a meaningful result? What's the result that you want to get from this code? I think you should throw the function out. You can do the same thing with aggregation and it will work better. Since you shouldn't use this code and I'm not competent with SQL, I won't try to translate it into SQL.